# header php function add additional characters in a variable

Tags: php

I have a weird problem with my code. When I use header to reload my page it adds the following characters in  $the_post_id variable-->  %020 .
The file starts with ob_start(); function.
Without header the $the_post_id variable works fine.
But when I use the following code

```
header("Location:edit.php?source= $the_post_id");

//var_dump($the_post_id);
```

then I have the following URL:
http://localhost/newstheme/admin/edit.php?source=%20128

Normally I expect to have this:
http://localhost/newstheme/admin/edit.php?source=128

Comment: It's because of the space you put after `=`.

Comment: `%20` is the URL encoding of a space character.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. You've right.

Comment: always `exit()` after a `header('Location:..')`, otherwise the script happily continues executing until its finished while the send user is on a new request. Usually it's not needed and it opens security issues as well.